# How to make the content dynamic using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

My question is abit theoretical.
I'm making the website where admin can upload the Exam papers on different category using PHP and MySql & I have the database called Our_Paper and inside it I have a table called Paperwithus.
[This is the user view of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfm7V.png):

There is an option i.e  category and six option are there..But I don't want to hard code that container for the category section like : `

```
<div class="C++_section"></div>
<div class="CN_section"></div>
<div class="DBMS_section"></div>
<div class="EDC_section"></div>
<div class="MP_section"></div>
```

`
I wants that,while uploading paper the admin enter the category of the paper and i want that if that category is already present then, the the paper should be added in the existing category but if that category is not present then the is should be created and paper should be added on the created category.
Eg :
If the DBMS category is already created :then paper should be added in that dbms category.
If the C++  category is not created : then category should be created and paper should be added on that category.

My question is abit Theoretical.. But please answer it.

Comment: Is it a homework / colleague assignment ?

Comment: No, i'ts my personal project.

Comment: You've explained what you're trying to achieve but haven't explained the problem you're having with it. Write the code to do what you've outlined here and come back with specific questions on aspects you have trouble with.

Comment: Sounds like you need a form for the admin to enter the category data and save it to the database, and then elsewhere you need some PHP to fetch the list of categories from the database, loop through them and display them. Both of these are fairly simple, standard tasks in a PHP application. It's not clear where you're stuck...the question is too vague. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask